# Converting Strings to their code points

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, astral-plane

I have to convert a large amount of characters to their Unicode Code Point equivalents. I was using the following code to do this conversion:

```
string sample = "b";
int utf32 = char.ConvertToUtf32(sample, 0);
string codePoint = string.Format("{0:X}", utf32);
```

This works for the more normal characters, but then I have characters like these `ǎ` where the actual string is comprises 2 chars `a (U-0061)` and `'̌' (U-030C)`. The function `ConverToUtf32(string, int)` there only returns the first (or the other depending on the index) character where I was actually expecting `U-0103`. Using `ConvertToUtf32(char, char)` does not work since that requires chars at a higher code point.

Is there another function that I can use to convert strings to their code points, or maybe a calculation that I can perform?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have to convert a large amount of characters to their Unicode Code Point equivalents.

That does not seem to be what you're actually asking for. If you have characters from the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane) (BMP), then each `char` corresponds to exactly one code point. Converting to UTF-32 won't change anything about that.

The `ConvertToUtf32()` method, and especially the overload that takes two `char`s are for handling codepoints that are not from the BMP. But that doesn't seem to be what you need.

What you actually seem to be asking for is to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) the string into “Normalization Form Canonical Composition” (NFC). To do that, use [the `string.Normalize()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx):

```
string decomposed = "\x0061\x030C";
string composed = decomposed.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
foreach (char c in composed)
    Console.WriteLine("U+{0:X4}", (int)c);
```

This will print “U+01CE”, that's [LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CARON](http://codepoints.net/U+01CE), which seems to be what you wanted. (U+030C is [COMBINING CARON](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/30c/index.htm), so the result is U+01CE LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CARON. If you really wanted U+0103 [LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH BREVE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/103/index.htm), you would need to use U+0306 [COMBINING BREVE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/306/index.htm) instead.)

Comment: Great answer, just what I needed! I came upon normalization but never realized I needed it.

Comment: Please note that normalization form C does not mean "no combining marks".

Comment: Thanks, that one I found out afterwards. If I'm getting it right, normalization seems to be for converting to [precomposed characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) where possible. But where there are none, it keeps them in their decomposed form. I had to figure out a modified solution for this.